# Passing an array of Child objects to a function that accepts Parent*

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, avr-gcc

I am working on an embedded platform with limited capabilities, so vectors/STL are not available.

This may be a trivial problem, but I do not have much experience in C++ (only C and C#, which may make me blind to an obvious c++ way to do it).

Consider the following example:

```
class Parent {
};

class Child : public Parent {
};

void Test(Parent* parents, uint8_t parentCount) {
    // Accessing parent[x] is problematic when 'parents' contains a derived type
}

int main() {
    // This is OK
    Parent parents[3];
    Test(parents, 3);

    // This causes problems
    Child children[3];
    Test(children, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously it is problematic to iterate over *parents* in *Test()*, if a pointer to an array of derived classes is provided, because the memory footprint of *Parent* is assumed during the iteration.

The only solution I see is to pass an array of pointers of type *Parent* (Parent** parents), but that seems cumbersome. Is there some C++ mechanism I am not aware of, like passing the array as a reference or something?

Comment: Make `Test` a template function? Use array of pointers (not that I really recommend it, unless your classes are polymorphic). The solution (these or others) depends very much on use-case.

Answer (score 7):

You could use this approach:

```
template <class T>
void Test(T* parents, uint8_t parentCount) {
    // Code that accesses parent[x]
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
int main() {

    Parent parents[3];
    Test(parents, 3);

    Child children[3];
    Test(children, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not specify the template type for function.  You should let the compiler deduce it for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: As I pointed out, the standard template library is not available.

Comment: @Rev1.0 This does not use the standard template library.  This is making your own template function.

Comment: @Rev1.0 This is not from the STL, It just uses templates which are part of C++ language.

Comment: Yes that's it. It is not STL. This is the elegant way to overcome C++ native vectors problem: vectors are passed by passing pointer to the first element and it looks the same as plain pointer.

Comment: @DmitriyZapevalov I think you mean array.  A vector is not converted to a pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right. For c++ array is appropriate name :)

Comment: Ah OK, I somehow assumed that template support is not available at all. I haven't read about C++ templates yet, but from what I get its similar to c# generics and the STL is equivalent to the C# libraries that provide general purpose generic classes. I am going to do some reading now...

Comment: @MarkoPopovic: I have one issue with this solution, is there a way to specify a base type (like Parent) for the template? In C# you could do "GenericList<T> where T : Parent" and work with that type without requiring a cast or type check within the generic function/class.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Don't let the similar syntax fool you, this is not the same as C# generics. The template mechanism creates a new instance of the function/class for every new type during compilation. It is possible that something similar to what you want could be achieved using **template metaprogramming** but I would advise not to try since you can't use STL. Implementing that from scratch requires excellent knowledge of C++ and templates.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So in the end, I either use this approach and have the trouble of type checking within the method (not sure how much trouble this really is in C++), or I go for the Parent** approach (as pointed out by user2079303) and get a clean method implementation at the cost of some overhead when calling it.

Comment: OP says "an array of derived classes is provided" which tells me a mix of different derived classes can be in the one array passed to the function. This solution doesn't support this.

Comment: @ytoledano To have a mix of different derived classes in an array (in C++), you need an array like this `Parent parents[length]`, and then assign different derived classes to the elements. But then, the original version of the method (which takes pointer to Parent) can be used. I think the biggest problem is that you guys want to use C++ templates to have all the features of C# generics.

Answer (score 3):

If template is not an option and when the user of `Test` can not depend on `Child` and can't even know it's size, then you can use an array of pointers:

```
void Test(Parent** parents, uint8_t parentCount);

int main() {
    Child children[n];
    Child* pointers[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pointers[i] = &children[i];
    Test(pointers);
}
```

Note that in this trivial example, we *do* know the size of the object whose pointers we pass, but in general, we may not be able to make that assumption for all users of `Test`.

Comment: This approach was my initial one, to quote myself: "The only solution I see is to pass an array of pointers of type Parent (Parent** parents), but that seems cumbersome." But thanks for verifying this though.

Comment: @Rev1.0 yeah, I noticed. This is here for the people, who are looking for a solution and to whom the other answers aren't an option.

Comment: This is the correct solution. A solution which passes a template array doesn't work for arrays that have a mix of different derived classes. If you could use STL you'd use a vector of unique_ptr or shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use templates, you can do this:

```
class Parent {
};

class Child : public Parent {
};

void Test(Parent* parents, uint8_t parentCount, uint16_t parentSize) {
    for (uint8_t ii = 0; ii < parentCount; ++ii) {
        void* parentvoid = reinterpret_cast<char*>(parents) + ii * parentSize;
        Parent* parent = parentvoid;
    }
}

int main() {
    Parent parents[3];
    Test(parents, 3, sizeof(parents[0]));

    Child children[3];
    Test(children, 3, sizeof(children[0]));
}
```

Comment: Interesting but somewhat messy approach. I hoped C++ would makes things cleaner ;) I guess I would prefer the "array of pointer" approach in comparison to this. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @Rev1.0: Well, the "array of pointers" approach is less efficient, and I figured you wouldn't want that since you're apparently on a super-constrained system, but it is certainly workable.